# Restrict lifetime parameter to scope of parameters of a function

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following example

```
trait MyTrait<'a> {
    type N: 'a;

    fn func(&'a self) -> Self::N;
}

fn myfunc<'a, T: 'a + MyTrait<'a>>(g: T) {
    g.func();
}

fn main() {}
```

Compiling this small program fails with:

```
error[E0597]: `g` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     g.func();
  |     ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9 | }
  | - borrowed value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 7:1...
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | fn myfunc<'a, T: 'a + MyTrait<'a>>(g: T) {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As far as I understand, the lifetime parameter `'a` is not restricted and could be arbitrary. However, `g` is a parameter and its lifetime is only the function scope, therefore it does not satisfy the condition of lifetime `'a` in the definition of method `func`.

What I really want is that the associated type `N` is always restricted to the lifetime of `self` in `MyTrait`. That's why I came up with the explicit lifetime parameter `'a` of `MyTrait`. I want function `myfunc` to work, i.e. `'a` should somehow be restricted to the lifetime of of the parameter `g`.

What is the "correct" way to solve this problem?

A very simple example is

```
struct MyPtr<'a> {
    x: &'a usize,
}

struct MyStruct {
    data: Vec<usize>,
}

impl<'a> MyTrait<'a> for MyStruct {
    type N = MyPtr<'a>;

    fn func(&'a self) -> Self::N {
        MyPtr { x: &self.data[0] }
    }
}
```

Note that this is extremely simplified, of course. The idea is that `N` always contains a reference to something contained in `MyTrait` and should therefore never outlive `MyTrait`.

Comment: Why do you want to constrain `N` to the lifetime of `self`? Could you show us an example implementation of `MyTrait`? Maybe you just need to change `&'a self` to `&self`.

Comment: “What I really want is that the associated type `N` is always restricted to the lifetime of `self`.” I’d like to point out that the `:` in the context of lifetimes means “outlives”, not the other way around. So `N: 'a` does not really restrict `N`, it just says that it lives at least as long as `self`, which should be true anyway for the struct type to be well-formed.

Comment: Nevertheless, you still might need to put it down explicitly, e.g. for your example to work. I just wanted to make it clear, that this “restriction” works the other way around, you do not restrict it to the lifetime of `self`, you demand that it lives longer than `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not to bind a generic lifetime, but to allow "any" lifetime:

```
fn myfunc<T: for<'a> MyTrait<'a>>(g: T) {
    g.func();
}
```

Fully working example in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eacbfd30db8a3da18a326d37de5a0dd6&version=stable&mode=debug).

The best source for an explanation is [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35595491/1103681).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where can I find something about this strange construct (I've never seen that before)?

Comment: @fifr I’m afraid, [RFC 1214](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1214-projections-lifetimes-and-wf.md) is the only official source that I’m aware of that kind of tries to explain `for<…>`, which is, well, unfortunate.

Comment: The best source for an explanation for the `for<...>` syntax is now http://stackoverflow.com/a/35595491/1103681